# Creating a new dataframe based on statistics calculated from a previous data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, calculation

I have the following data frame

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                   A = c(50, 150, 200, 250, 100, NA),
                   B = c(10, NA, 30, NA, NA, 10))
```

I want to create a new data frame that tells me the percent of points that are not NA such that

```
   dat2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2),
                        A =c( 100, 66.6),
                        B = c(66.6, 33.3))
```

I can figure how to calculate the values in R, but  I can't figure out how to place the calculations into a new data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a  group by 'ID' with `mean` of the non-NA logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise_all(~ 100 *mean(!is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#     ID     A     B
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 100    66.7
#2     2  66.7  33.3
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(. ~ ID, dat, FUN = function(x) 100 *mean(!is.na(x)), na.action  = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, you can do that very efficiently :

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
dat[,.(lapply(.SD, function(x) 100*mean(!is.na(x))), by = "ID"]
```

`.SD` means *Subset of Data* you apply the `mean` + `is.na` combination over all your columns. You can also apply that to a subset of columns using `.SDcols` (e.g. *A* column) :

```r
dat[,.(lapply(.SD, function(x) 100*mean(!is.na(x))),
      by = "ID", .SDcols = c("A")]
```